# The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.57 SMTP;

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

When I m trying to send mail through my C# Code above error is showing. I have searched for possibly all solution but I do not get the solution. I am using the below Code:

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage("SenderMail",Email);
        mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
        mail.Subject = "An email from Office365";
        mail.Body = "<html><body><h1>Hello world</h1></body></html>";
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.office365.com");
        client.Port = 587;
        client.EnableSsl = true;
        client.UseDefaultCredentials = false; // Important: This line of code must be executed before setting the NetworkCredentials object, otherwise the setting will be reset (a bug in .NET)
        NetworkCredential cred = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("Sendermail", "Password");
        client.Credentials = cred;
        client.Send(mail);
```

Comment: Are you 100% certain the credentials (user: Sendmail, Password: Password) is correct, including capitalisation?

Comment: Yes Neil I Cross Checked it by logging in my Account @Neil

Comment: The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.57 SMTP; Client was not authenticated to send anonymous mail during MAIL FROM [MA1PR01CA0093.INDPRD01.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM]

Comment: try putting the full email address in the sender credentials (e.g. sendermail@office365.com)

Comment: it's just a sample. I have used a full email address

Comment: Please verify your credentials. if it is wrong we will get the same error message..

Answer (score 2):

1- I believe the following is missing from your code.

client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;

2- Dont set UseDefaultCredentials value to false. Keep it to its default value. Just remove the line.

This worked for me.

Comment: Thanks for your response but it doesn't work!  same error.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't, then I believe you may need to enable client sending from your Office365 account.  See [this page](https://weblogs.asp.net/sreejukg/send-email-using-office-365-account-and-c) for details.

Comment: I have read this already and in my coding you can see i have done all the things mentioned there. Is there an setting like gmail where we allow access to third party application to send emails.

Answer (score 0):

**Context**: I faced the same error, and I thought my credentials were good, because it was working okay every day. I tried to debug, looked for a solution in internet (even in this stackoverflow question-thread), and I spent lots of minutes with no good result.

**Solution**: Finally, I tried my "supposed correct" credentials on [outlook](http://www.outlook.com) web client and logged in. Result: I got this message: "*you password expired!* "
then I updated the password in web client, I updated credentials and my code and that's it, it worked okay as usual.

**Additional info**: You may consider to keep password (encrypted) somewhere else (not in source code), so that it can be easily updated.