# China office 365 outlook stmp email not work

Tags: c#, outlook

exception :
[image]

my code :

```
        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
        SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient(host:"smtp.partner.outlook.cn",port:587);
        mail.From = new MailAddress("");
        mail.To.Add(    ""  );
        mail.Subject = "Test"   ;
        mail.Body = @"Test" ;
        SmtpServer.Port = 587   ;
        SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(userName:"",password: "") ;
        SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true ;
        SmtpServer.Send(mail);
```

error msg :

```
System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.57 SMTP; Client was not authenticated to send anonymous mail during MAIL FROM [SHAPR01CA022.CHNPR01.prod.partner.outlook.cn]
```

it looks like the office 365 partner in china have some different setting and cause this problem.

#### what i searched and tried :

- [5.7.57 SMTP - Client was not authenticated to send anonymous mail during MAIL FROM error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30342884/5-7-57-smtp-client-was-not-authenticated-to-send-anonymous-mail-during-mail-fr)
- [The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.57 SMTP;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43513783/the-smtp-server-requires-a-secure-connection-or-the-client-was-not-authenticated)

Comment: you need to use `microsoft.exchange.webservices.dll` / package, and a valid user

Comment: @T.S. thanks,i'm trying your way now.

Comment: Also see this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6244694/send-smtp-email-using-system-net-mail-via-exchange-online-office-365   I personally never used `smtpClient` against office365. But EWS client - yes. Possibly, sending email is not too bad. In my case I mostly read email but also send.